# Opensearch issues with json field names containing []

Tags: logstash, opensearch

here is a sample object that comes into os logstash

```
"MyObject": {
  "normalField": "asdf",
  "additionalData:long:subObject[0]": "banking",
  "additionalData:long:subObject[1]": "banking"
}
```

now the problem being when you want to try perform edits on these fields with the [0] logstash and the ruby plugins interpret that as a sub object not as being part of the name. i have tried escaping with [ or [ and it still has the same effect

ie from a ruby script this does not work

```
event.remove('additionalData:long:subObject[1]')
```

i found some people with similar issues and they did a regex replace before parsing to json buy my issue is this being from kafka its already in a json input with " codec => json"

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [OpenSearch Ingest Pipeline](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/ingest-pipelines/index/) with a regular expression to strip these brackets from your JSON document before it's indexed.

The [mutate string processor](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/data-prepper/pipelines/configuration/processors/mutate-string/) would enable you to do this with ease.